# Allowing Magic Arrow and Bow to stack?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, weapons, stacking

Is there any downside to allowing the Magic Arrows bonus to stack with a Magic Bow bonus, other than it is not rules-as-written?

Comment: I'd note that there's already a way to make magic arrows more powerful with a magic bow - putting different enhancements on the arrows than you have on the bow - as well as the fact that ranged attackers are already generally considered more powerful than melee because they full attack much more often.  Neither is exactly an answer to your question, but might be things to think about.

Answer (score 7):

### It would be somewhat unbalancing

A +1 weapon is four times cheaper to come by than a +2 weapon. While there are some other benefits of having an actual +2 bonus instead of two stacked +1 bonuses (like adding more hardness), the core benefit is the increased to hit chance and damage.

If you allowed them to stack, you could get most of the effect of a +2 weapon for half the price, and much earlier. This is not balanced.

There is some downside that half of this cost are arrows that are consumed when used, so part of the cost would be recurring. Eventually this would catch up, or become even more expensive. Still, at 50 arrows, that is a lot of fights, by the time, you run out, you probably have made enough experience and money to upgrade to combining a +2 weapon and +2 arrows.

Also, at the high end, a normal magical weapon is capped at +5 enhancement bonus, but allowing them to stack, you could get to an overall +10 bonus.

Answer (score 6):

## Are more caster–archers a downside?

Instituting a house rule that says that ***An enhancement bonus on a ranged weapon stacks with any enhancement bonus on its ammunition*** benefits most those archers and crossbow wielders who have inexpensive access to those enhancement bonuses, and, for the most part, that will mean those archers and crossbow wielders who have access to the 3rd-level Sor/Wiz and Pal and 4th-level Clr spell [***greater magic weapon***](http://dndsrd.net/spellsMtoO.html#greater-magic-weapon) [trans] (*Player's Handbook* 251–2). (Sure, you three guys with slings? You benefit, too. And, hey, blowgun guy? Yeah, you benefit, too. Congrats. Moving on.)

While arguments can be marshaled in favor of buying an enhancement bonus higher than +1 instead of relying on a spell for that higher enhancement bonus, when it comes down to it, because of the value the game places on magic weapons generally, even if it costs two spells, it's really difficult to ignore the substantial benefits of scaling up one's weapon *twice*.

Here's the endgame: An archer has 200,000+ gp ***+1 [collision](http://dndsrd.net/psionicItemsAW.html#collision) [flaming](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsAW.html#flaming) [frost](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsAW.html#frost) [seeking](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsAW.html#seeking) [shock](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsAW.html#shock) [speed](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsAW.html#speed) composite longbow*** and all the masterwork arrows he can carry. Then he casts on his ranged weapon and his day's ammunition the *greater magic weapon* spell (therefore casting two spells). With a caster level of 20 or higher, their enhancement bonuses go from +1 to +5, resulting in a +8 on attack rolls for an hour per caster level and representing a savings of over 3.7 million gp. (Silly but true: a [*+14 composite longbow*](http://dndsrd.net/epicMagicItems.html#epic-magic-weapons) has a price of at least 3.9 million gp. Fifty *+5 magic arrows* are only a little north of 50,000 gp, though.)

Using no shenanigans and the core rules at their most basic, a character using a karma bead from a [*strand of prayer beads*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsWI.html#strand-of-prayer-beads) and who has circling him an [*ioun stone*](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsWI.html#ioun-stones) (orange prism) can do this at level 15. It's also really good to give both ranged weapons and ammunition only a +4 enhancement bonus each at caster level 16 (so potentially character level 11), or just a +3 or +2 each a few character levels earlier.

Details can be debated, but the wider points are these:

1. The stacking enhancement bonuses see the character hitting more often and dealing more damage than the game typically expects at the levels at which the stacking enhancement bonuses are available. Having an additional and easily accessible bonus on attack rolls and damage over the course of a character's career is pretty huge, especially for archers who can achieve impressive rates of fire.
2. Having stacking enhancement bonuses doesn't consume excessive resources at the character levels at which having those bonuses is meaningful. As mentioned, the importance of a wizard's 3rd-level or a cleric's 4th-level spells can be debated, but it's really hard for a level 12 cleric (who is also an archer) to look at his 4th-level spells and say, "I *don't* want +6 on attack rolls and damage during this adventuring day," when he's already prepared *death ward*, *divine power*, and *freedom of movement*.

Depending on the optimization environment of your table, these points may be moot. An optimized contemporary *Dungeons & Dragons 3.5* archer will already be hitting often enough and dealing enough damage to endanger CR-appropriate foes, probably downing many foes with one full attack and probably doing so all day long. On the other hand, no optimized contemporary *3.5* archer would *ignore* an inexpensive all-adventuring-day bonus on attack and damage rolls, either.

In an environment that sees less optimization, I assume the house rule goes unnoticed, but it's still possible for a player to sit down at the table and say, "I want to play Legolas," discover this house rule, and dominate combat *accidentally*. Every cleric has access to the *greater magic weapon* spell, after all.

In an environment wherein PCs never reach higher than ECL 5, the house rule probably won't get a lot of attention. Chances are an archer in the party'll stack the enhancement bonuses of his masterwork bow and masterwork arrows, but at those character levels, that's expensive. (Seriously, if you're level 3 when you can fire 3–5 arrows *per full attack*, 7 gp per arrow is no joke!) In such an environment, you can probably implement this house rule with little risk to your campaign's integrity.

I know this because this was already a thing.

### Before the *3.5* revision, this is how the rules worked

In *Dungeons & Dragons, Third Edition*, a ranged weapon's enhancement bonus stacked with its ammunition's enhancement bonus. The *Dungeon Master's Guide* (2000) on **Bonuses from Magic**, in part, says

> Different named bonus types all stack, but **usually a named bonus does not stack** with another bonus of the same name (**except for** enhancement bonuses of armor and shields, **enhancement bonuses to ranged weapons and their ammunition**, dodge bonuses, synergy bonuses, and circumstance bonuses). (176 and emphasis mine)

Thus what the question asks was actually how things were from 2000—2003. The rule is a vertebra in the spine of [Frank Trollman's cleric–archer](http://www.niftymessageboard.com/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=39391&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=0), for instance, that was often pointed to on the now-defunct Wizards of the Coast message boards as an example of how the cleric is a better fighter than the fighter.

I could find no mention of *why* this change was made, not in the treeware *Dragon* **3.5 Revision Update** columns that appeared in issues #304–9 and not in the digital **Revision Spotlight** columns that once appeared on Wizards of the Coast's site (and that don't seem to be preserved in the *Internet Archive* [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160815000000*/http://dnd.wizards.com/go/rsa/archive) but are still available [here](http://rpg.nobl.ca/archive.php?x=dnd/rsa/archive)). But this rule—and the *greater magic weapon* spell that used to be +1 every 3 levels—were changed by the *3.5* revision.

Comment: There's no way I could've found that cleric–archer messageboard thread without [this post](https://forums.giantitp.com/showsinglepost.php?p=21875458&postcount=51) on the *Giant in the Playground* forums. Thanks you for your fandom, folks.

Answer (score 4):

Per SRD:

> Magic Ammunition and Breakage
>
> When a magic arrow, crossbow bolt, shuriken, or sling bullet misses its target, there is a 50% chance it breaks or otherwise is rendered useless. A magic arrow, bolt, bullet, or shuriken that hits is destroyed.

The weapon bonus on your bow would cost:

1. 2,000 gp
2. 8,000 gp

for a difference of 6,000 gp. +1 arrows would cost 2,000 gp per 50 arrows, or 40 gp per arrow. Again, counting only enhancement cost because all other costs are equal. So, if allowed to stack, you would have 150 shots before your scheme would reach the price of a +2 bow.

Counting 5 rounds per encounter, 3 encounters per day, you would have *at most* 15 arrows shot in one adventuring day. Because [it takes 3 or 4 adventuring days to level up](https://forums.giantitp.com/showsinglepost.php?p=17215383&postcount=2), this combo would be a significantly cheaper option for the best part of your character's career.

---

The other problem about this would be putting +3 arrow on a +3 bow. Doable pre-epic, but +6 bonus and above is meant only for epic characters, deities etc. 3.5 didn't have the bounded accuracy, but this combined bonus would overcome resistances no mortal was meant to overcome.

Comment: Double-check the math of your theory-crafting. 6th level character with rapid shot would routinely fire 15 arrows *per combat*.  Prior to 6th level, they'd go through 10 arrows per combat with that feat.  That's 10-15 combats (or about one level) to go through that price difference.

Comment: @TheoBrinkman this assumes a player who was allowed to do this would chose feats that increase arrow consumption rather than decrease it.

Comment: @TheoBrinkman if it was me, I'd optimize the damage per arrow rather than arrows per round. There is a lot of possible builds, so I have chosen to stick to the basics and explain *how* I calculated it, rather than guess every possibility.

Comment: @Molot, you'd rather have a chance to do an additional +1 damage (optimizing damage per arrow) than an additional 1d8+1 damage (optimizing arrows per round) with the same equipment?  Seems like an odd 'optimization' choice.  But it still doesn't address your statement that "you would have *at most* 15 arrows shot in one adventuring day", when that accounts for 1 combat encounter instead.

Answer (score 3):

Just one more thing to be mentioned:

> A few very powerful monsters are vulnerable only to epic weapons; that is, magic weapons with at least a +6 enhancement bonus. Such creatures’ natural weapons are also treated as epic weapons for the purpose of overcoming damage reduction.

So if you can put a +3 arrow and a +3 bow together to make an attack with +6 enhancement bonus, you are actually attacking with an Epic weapon that can bypass Epic DR (e.g. DR 10/Epic). I personally don't feel this is reasonable.